# Select only elements that have no children except the child element is a <wbr></wbr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to select elements that have no child elements. This is because I want to select all the texts in a very complex website.

I do this like so:

```
$mainSection.filter(":not(:has(*))");
```

But then there are some special cases like this one:

```
<p>Some interesting text <wbr></wbr> that has an "optional word break" tag in it</p>
```

In this case I want to select the p, even if there is child element in it. But just if the child element is a wbr tag.

Comment: Something like `$mainSection.remove("wbr").filter(":not(:has(*))");`

Comment: Good point. The Problem with this is, that it really removes the wbr tag. And I don't want that. I just want to filter for elements that contain a wbr tag but nothing else.

Comment: Note that `wbr` is much like `br` in that there is only a start tag; there is no end tag (unless you're using XHTML, in which case you should still represent it as `<wbr />` and not `<wbr></wbr>`).

Comment: “There are some special cases like this one” suggests that there are other elements as well that you wish to allow (maybe e.g. `<br>`, forced line break), but the question does not specify them. And since it’s unclear why you are doing this, it’s possible that the *real* problem is something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have another `:not()` *within* the `:has()` for excluding certain child elements:

```
$mainSection.filter(":not(:has(:not(wbr)))");
```

On a side note, if the outer `:not()` is the only part of your `.filter()` selector string, you can simply swap the `.filter()` out for a `.not()` to make the code a little less confusing:

```
$mainSection.not(":has(:not(wbr))");
```

Both of these statements mean the same thing in English: exclude elements from the set `$mainSection` that have any child elements that are not `wbr`.

Comment: I want to select elements that doesn't contain any other elements except if they contain a wbr tag. What you do here doesn't work for me.

Comment: "I want to select elements that doesn't contain any other elements except if they contain a wbr tag." That's *exactly* what my answer does. If it doesn't work for you, something else is wrong or you haven't expressed your question correctly.

Comment: Particularly, what does `$mainSection` contain? If it contains your `p` elements, then my answer should work. If it contains something else, like the document element, or an arbitrary sectioning element, then how does your original code work in the first place?

Comment: You are right. It works. And it also makes sense by now.